# Constructing an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

For every $n \ge 5$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$,  I need to construct an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$ with exactly $5$ non zero terms.

I am pretty clueless on how to even start with this one, my original idea was to use Cyclotomic Polynomials but that doesn't seem to work here.

Any help???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:- [Eisenstein's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Criterion)

For example try $x^{5}+5x^{4}+25x^{3}+625x+5$

Comment: Interesting idea, so for a degree $n$ we can construct  $f = x^n + 5x^4 + 25x^3 + 625x + 5$

Comment: Yep....anything you like . I just chose the coefficients randomly . You can use any prime. As long as it satisfies the criterion.